# How to iteratively explode a nested json with index using posexplode_outer

Tags: python, json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a nested json that I need to explode using posexplode_outer function

```
def flatten_df(nested_df): 
    for column in nested_df.columns:
        array_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:5] == 'array']
    for column in array_cols:
        nested_df=nested_df.select('*',F.posexplode_outer(nested_df["`"+column+"`"]).alias("position",column))
    
    nested_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:6] == 'struct']
    
    if len(nested_cols) == 0:
        return nested_df
    
    flat_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:6] != 'struct']
    
    flat_df = nested_df.select(flat_cols +
                            [F.col(nc+'.'+c).alias(nc+'_'+c)
                                for nc in nested_cols
                                for c in nested_df.select(nc+'.*').columns])
    
    return flatten_df(flat_df)
```

I get ambiguous column name error

> An error was encountered: "Reference <column_name> is ambiguous, could
> be: <column_name>, <column_name>.;"

Can anyone help me resolve this error. Input to the function is a JSON like below which is stored in a Spark dataframe. The JSON is highly nested.

```
{
        "template": 
            {
                "id": "9",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "id": "header",
                        "value": "Find the Right Marker for the Job"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "section1-header",
                        "value": "Desk-Style Dry Erase Markers"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "section2-header",
                        "value": "Pen-Style Dry Erase Markers"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "section3-header",
                        "value": "Jumbo Washable Markers"
                    }
                ],
                "paragraph": [
                    {
                        "id": "description1",
                        "value": ["Desk-style wipe off easily "] 
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "description2",
                        "value": ["Pen-style "]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "description3",
                        "value": ["banners."] 
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "description4",
                        "value": ["posters"] 
                    }
                ],
                "image": [
                    {
                        "id": "section1-image",
                        "assetId": "S"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "section2-image",
                        "assetId": "A" 
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "section3-image",
                        "assetId": "34"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "section4-image",
                        "assetId": "36"
                    }
                ]
            }
            })
```

The expected output for the above example JSON is

[image]

Comment: could you add sample input dataset and expected output.

Comment: edited the question with sample input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Probaly your schema contains columns that have repeated name after flattening.
Try to call print schema on flatted df.

That error message happens when column names in a data frame are non-unique and the analyser cannot determine which column you are referencing.

In that case you either need to resolve the method that produces the dataframe or positionally access columns and alias them so they have unique names.

Comment: thanks @milos. The same input file works with 'explode_outer' function. But it is not working with posexplode_outer. I dont know how posexplode_outer is different from explode_outer

Answer (score 0):

Below is my try to flatten the nested DF, Perhaps this is helpful -

> Written in scala, but can be implemented in pyspark with minimal change

### Load the test data provided

```scala
 val data =
      """
        |{
        |   "template": {
        |       "id": "9",
        |       "header": [{
        |               "id": "header",
        |               "value": "Find the Right Marker for the Job"
        |           },
        |           {
        |               "id": "section1-header",
        |               "value": "Desk-Style Dry Erase Markers"
        |           },
        |           {
        |               "id": "section2-header",
        |               "value": "Pen-Style Dry Erase Markers"
        |           },
        |           {
        |               "id": "section3-header",
        |               "value": "Jumbo Washable Markers"
        |           }
        |       ],
        |       "paragraph": [{
        |               "id": "description1",
        |               "value": ["Desk-style wipe off easily "]
        |           },
        |           {
        |               "id": "description2",
        |               "value": ["Pen-style "]
        |           },
        |           {
        |               "id": "description3",
        |               "value": ["banners."]
        |           },
        |           {
        |               "id": "description4",
        |               "value": ["posters"]
        |           }
        |       ],
        |       "image": [{
        |               "id": "section1-image",
        |               "assetId": "S"
        |           },
        |           {
        |               "id": "section2-image",
        |               "assetId": "A"
        |           },
        |           {
        |               "id": "section3-image",
        |               "assetId": "34"
        |           },
        |           {
        |               "id": "section4-image",
        |               "assetId": "36"
        |           }
        |       ]
        |   }
        |}
      """.stripMargin
    val df = spark.read.option("multiLine", true)
      .json(Seq(data).toDS())

    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |template                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
      * +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |[[[header, Find the Right Marker for the Job], [section1-header, Desk-Style Dry Erase Markers], [section2-header, Pen-Style Dry Erase Markers], [section3-header, Jumbo Washable Markers]], 9, [[S, section1-image], [A, section2-image], [34, section3-image], [36, section4-image]], [[description1, [Desk-style wipe off easily ]], [description2, [Pen-style ]], [description3, [banners.]], [description4, [posters]]]]|
      * +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- template: struct (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- header: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      * |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- image: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      * |    |    |    |-- assetId: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- paragraph: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      * |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |    |-- value: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
      */
```

### Rename the struct col and flatten the schema

```scala
    val p = df.withColumn("template", col("template")
      .cast(
        """
          |struct<
          |header:array<struct<header_id:string, header_value:string>>,
          |id:string,
          |image:array<struct<image_value:string, image_id:string>>,
          |paragraph:array<struct<paragraph_id:string, paragraph_value:array<string>>>
          |>
        """.stripMargin.replaceAll("\n", "")))
      .selectExpr("template.*")
      .withColumn("paragraph", expr("TRANSFORM(paragraph, x -> named_struct('paragraph_id', x.paragraph_id, " +
        "'paragraph_value', x.paragraph_value[0]))"))

    p.show(false)
    p.printSchema()

    /**
      * +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |header                                                                                                                                                                                   |id |image                                                                                 |paragraph                                                                                                                   |
      * +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |[[header, Find the Right Marker for the Job], [section1-header, Desk-Style Dry Erase Markers], [section2-header, Pen-Style Dry Erase Markers], [section3-header, Jumbo Washable Markers]]|9  |[[S, section1-image], [A, section2-image], [34, section3-image], [36, section4-image]]|[[description1, Desk-style wipe off easily ], [description2, Pen-style ], [description3, banners.], [description4, posters]]|
      * +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- header: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      * |    |    |-- header_id: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- header_value: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- id: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- image: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      * |    |    |-- image_value: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- image_id: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- paragraph: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
      * |    |    |-- paragraph_id: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- paragraph_value: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

### `posexplode` each of the array as different dataframe and then join using `position` column

```scala
    val p1 = p.select($"id", posexplode_outer($"header")).selectExpr("col.*", "pos as position", "id")
    val p2 = p.select($"id", posexplode_outer($"image")).selectExpr("col.*", "pos as position")
    val p3 = p.select($"id", posexplode_outer($"paragraph")).selectExpr("col.*", "pos as position")

    p1.join(p2, "position")
        .join(p3, "position")
        .show(false)

    /**
      * +--------+---------------+---------------------------------+---+-----------+--------------+------------+---------------------------+
      * |position|header_id      |header_value                     |id |image_value|image_id      |paragraph_id|paragraph_value            |
      * +--------+---------------+---------------------------------+---+-----------+--------------+------------+---------------------------+
      * |2       |section2-header|Pen-Style Dry Erase Markers      |9  |34         |section3-image|description3|banners.                   |
      * |0       |header         |Find the Right Marker for the Job|9  |S          |section1-image|description1|Desk-style wipe off easily |
      * |1       |section1-header|Desk-Style Dry Erase Markers     |9  |A          |section2-image|description2|Pen-style                  |
      * |3       |section3-header|Jumbo Washable Markers           |9  |36         |section4-image|description4|posters                    |
      * +--------+---------------+---------------------------------+---+-----------+--------------+------------+---------------------------+
      */
```